# How can I optimize nested for loops in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw a  pattern in a 100x100 window using John Zelle’s graphics module, and  I am sure that the nested for loop is not the most efficient way to do it.
Any thoughts on how I can optimize the nested for loop? Here is the code:

```
def Penultimatedigitdesign(x,y,win,color):
    for Y in range(y,y+100,40):
        for X in range(x+20,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleInSqureTF(win,X,Y,"white",color)
        for X in range(x,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleInSqureTF(win,X,Y,color,"white")
    for Y in range(y+20,y+100,40):
        for X in range(x+20,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleInSqureTF(win,X,Y,color,"white")
        for X in range(x,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleInSqureTF(win,X,Y,"white",color)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the strategy for navigating multi-dimensional space optimally is to vectorize it. In other words, structure your starting state as a matrix, apply a function to the matrix, and ask the GPU to give you the output. In Python, numpy is the key library that does this.

In graphics programming, people write "shaders," which are basically functions that operate on a signle pixel. These can be applied to a matrix (i.e., all the pixels on the screen), so that the GPU, which is optimized for this type of work, can carry it out in parallel.

As far as how to specifically implement this for your use case, and for whatever graphics backend you are targeting, I can't say, because there aren't enough details. If this is just a learning exercise, iterating over each pixel and solving the problem procedurally is probably OK.